# New tag: "personalization-builder" for SFSE (not meta)

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I was wondering if we could have a new tag for marketing cloud's personalization builder. I got many question in that area but i cannot mark it properly. The Tag predictive intelligence and einstein are widely spread over different salesforce products. Therefore it might often be missunderstood.

Additionally all other tabs of marketing cloud already have their own tag (journeybuilder, emailstudio, contentbuilder, contactbuilder, ...) it would be quite fitting to create an own one for it aswell.

Examples that would fit that category from my own questions:

- [ProductCatalog Question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/203940/how-to-match-trackingcode-to-productcatalog)
- [Privacy Batch Api](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/220625/privacy-batch-api-understanding-and-implementation)
- [SSJS import historical purchase data into tracking](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/227196/understanding-ssjs-statusandrequestid-how-to-pass-this-data-to-einstein-trac)
- [Logic behind trackPageView questionable?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/211116/logic-behind-trackpageview-questionable)
- [Personalization builder status Console Errors](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/228278/export-personalization-builder-status-console-errors)
- [Which decimal seperator inside tracking](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/221921/collect-tracking-code-decimal-seperator)
- [PI Rule Manager](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/211111/pi-rule-manager-general-questions)
- [How to track on SKU-level](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/205841/predictive-web-how-to-track-on-sku-level)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anyone can create tags. You just add it to your post and boom, it's in the system.

I've added the tag to the first post in your question here. You should be able to add it to any of your own posts without issue. If you want to add it to any posts you do not own, simply suggest the edit and your changes will enter the review queue.